# Umbraco, how to add onChange functionality on dropdown content backoffice?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am having one document type which contains a dropdown list, I need to add a couple of things in it:

1. I need to display the Database table names in drop-down dynamically.
2. On the change of dropdown option, i need to display the selected table columns names in another drop-down.

Are above things possible by using only existing data types or it will require creating a custom template using razor syntaxes (if it is so then how the template will display directly in the back office content node?)

Can you please provide your views and any links for code/tutorials?

[screen shot of content form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plRt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the back office, you will need to do it in HTML and Angular, with an API controller to handle the DB lookup stuff.

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing built in to do dropdowns that depend on each other, so you'd have to create a new DataType to do it.

The process is to long to detail here, but here are some useful links on creating custom DocTypes in Umbraco 7.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/
http://velstand.info/tips/umbraco/to-create-a-datatype-by-using-external-data-sources/
https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/custom-property-editor-tutorial/

Comment: Is that possible to render the Template somehow in the backoffice content node/list, as i can create the form in the template with razor syntax and if it can be rendered in the backoffice content(where documenttype form get displayed) ???

Comment: Like in the above attached screen shot, weighted tag form can be created by using razor syntax html,  instead of predefined data types[document type]

Comment: Nope. No Razor in the editing interface for Umbraco Content, it all has to use Angular. The only way to use Razor in the back office is in your own custom trees/sections.

Comment: In my case on the selection of one drop-down other drop-down will get populated so should I create two separate custom property/data type or we can add multiple objects in the same custom property/datatype ???

Comment: In case if we can add multiple HTML objects then will the separate nodeId get assigned to each object, otherwise in backend how we will identify the object value?

Comment: I would have both fields on the same Data Type, it'll make things easier. You can store the two Ids as a JSON object and then create a PropertyConverter for the front end if you want.